# Deleting all files from a folder when view pages

Tags: php, file, delete-file

How to implement auto deleting all files from folder when view pages or without any clicks button, example someone visiting page index.php then automatic execute deleting all files in a folder?

Comment: For that you have to create ajax call.
At the time of page load, make ajax call, and put your file delete code over there

Comment: it may be silly question, but i want to ask: are folders at the server or client side?

Comment: server but execute when client load some pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator($dir);
    while($iterator->valid()) {
           @unlink($dir.$filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$i=0;
$handle = opendir($dir); 
while ($filename = readdir($handle))
{ 
   if($filename!="."&&$filename!="..")
   {
       if(!is_dir($dir.$filename))
       {
          @unlink($dir.$filename);
       }
       else
       del_cache($dir.$filename."/");
  }
}
});
```

It is called when the page is loaded. There is no need to call function.